# Show a string in different currency format with DataTables plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

having an unsigned integer, you can specify an option as rendering composed differently?

I would like to obtain, for example, the number 1.234,00

Currently I can only set an option.

I also tried to use different values such as:

`{"data": "value_scad", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number('.', ',', 2, '€ ')}`

Thank you for your help and I hope will be useful to other users.

Comment: did you tried the formatnumber function? here's a reference https://datatables.net/reference/option/formatNumber hope it helps

Comment: @kabstergo Thanks, thanks, thanks! Thanks to you, I finally solved the problem